# how to sort in a for loop (swift)

Tags: swift

```
let vehicles = ["unicycle" : 1, "bicycle":2, "tricycle":3, "quad bike": 4]
for (vehicleName, wheelCount) in vehicles {

    print (" \(vehicleName) has \(wheelCount) wheels")
      
}`
```

The printout result is:

> quad bike has 4 wheels unicycle has 1 wheels  tricycle has 3 wheels
> bicycle has 2 wheels

How can I sort them according to their number of wheels, so the printout can be like:

unicycle has 1 wheels
bicycle has 2 wheels
tricycle has 3 wheels
quad bike has 4 wheels

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use **[`sorted`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2296815-sorted)**:

```
let vehicles = ["unicycle" : 1, "bicycle": 2, "tricycle": 3, "quad bike": 4]
let sortedVehicles = vehicles.sorted { $0.value < $1.value }
for (vehicleName, wheelCount) in sortedVehicles {
    print ("\(vehicleName) has \(wheelCount) wheels")
}
```

**Output:**

```
unicycle has 1 wheels
bicycle has 2 wheels
tricycle has 3 wheels
quad bike has 4 wheels
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let vehicles = ["unicycle" : 1, "bicycle":2, "quad bike": 4, "tricycle":3]
let sortedVehicles = vehicles.sorted { $0.1 < $1.1 }
print(sortedVehicles) //Prints [(key: "unicycle", value: 1), (key: "bicycle", value: 2), (key: "tricycle", value: 3), (key: "quad bike", value: 4)]
sortedVehicles.forEach {
    print("\($0.key) has \($0.value) wheels")
}
```

Result:

```
unicycle has 1 wheels
bicycle has 2 wheels
tricycle has 3 wheels
quad bike has 4 wheels
```

Answer (score 0):

```objectivec
let vehicles = ["unicycle" : 1, "bicycle" : 2, "tricycle" : 3, "quadbike" : 4].sorted {
    return $0.value > $1.value
}
for (vehicieName, wheelCount) in vehicles {
    print("\(vehicieName) has \(wheelCount) wheels")
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, although being sorted backwards, this one also helps.

Comment: Ah my mistake, I am very happy to discuss the problem with you